# Better way for inject EJB bean to @Named or @ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb

Which way is better for inject EJB Bean? I have an EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class BrandModel implements BrandService {
//...
}
```

and I have JSF `@Named` bean, where I inject my EJB:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class BrandBean implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private BrandService brandService;
//...
}
```

but if I create a new `@Named` or `@ManagedBean`, for example `ClotherBean`, in which i will need to use the EJB `BrandModel`, which way is better for injecting the EJB? This:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ClotherBean implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private BrandService brandService;
//...
}
```

or to create a getter in `BrandBean` for `brandService` and use it this way:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ClotherBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private BrandBean brandBean;

    public void test(){
       brandBean.getBrandService().selectAll();
    }

}
```

Is there a difference between these two approaches? Or both are ways the same?

Comment: In my opinion first is better. In second example, you have additional layer - the BrandBean, and creating garbage on every request no matter if BrandBean is needed or not. My understanding is the BrandService is a independent stateless service, so use it any place you need it, without introducing another proxy/delegator.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is acceptable. But since Java 6+ @Inject is preferred. The behaviour has to be the same no matter what AS you use. Here is a little bit more about on this issue:

http://germanescobar.net/2010/04/4-areas-of-possible-confusion-in-jee6.html